# What is the difference between "Post", "PostFollow", and "PostComment"?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I want to know about the difference between "Post", "PostFollow", and "PostComment" in Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are all Activity Feeds entities:

- **Post**

  - **AutoPost:** A post generated by Microsoft Dynamics 365 by applying an auto post rule in case of an event, such as creation of an account or closure of a won opportunity. An auto post can be shown on a record wall or personal wall. The auto post text is localized.
  - **Manual Post (User Post):** A post created by a Microsoft Dynamics 365 user. A manual post can be shown on a record wall or personal wall.
- **PostComment:** A remark that is added on a post. A comment is related to a parent post. It cannot exist without a parent post. If a parent post is deleted, the post’s comments are deleted also.
- **PostLike:** An action taken by a user on a post that expresses that the user liked the post.
- **PostFollow:** An action taken by a user on a Microsoft Dynamics 365 record that enables that user to see the posts about the record on their personal wall.

[image]

You can take a deeper look of this reading the [introduction to activity feeds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547394.aspx) and the list of [activity feeds entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547452.aspx).